# storing code in a column and using it

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a column that has data, such as `year(date)` or `date-365`.

How do I use this text as code, not as text? Meaning, I'd like to be able to do something like

```
 me.ProjectName="ddddd " & MyColumnWithCode
```

and get `ddddd 2017` or `ddddd 10/21/2016`

I did google in every way I could think of and didn't get anything.

Comment: This sounds like a remarkably bad plan. Why not store code in the form module, where it's supposed to be, and use a `SELECT CASE` to execute the appropriate code. Storing code in a database is a generally bad idea, and opens the users up for a hack even after you've signed the database with a certificate.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? I don't think I care about hacks, this is an internal db in a huge company used by 3 people maybe. Whoever would be hacking us would have many more appealing targets. But I'm curious how this is done the right way. So, I have a drop down that fills in ProjectName for some options that are used more often. So, let's say there's a project that I know is run often, so I add an entry for it. I know that it should have the month_year appendix. Where can I put that info?

Comment: Lol it would be a challenge for the hacker to pick this db from tens of thousands of others. And i guess im not sure what doors this would open for him. If he finds this db that means he already hacked everything. I guess I'm curious how this would help with hacking, as well as doing it the right way

Comment: You might not care that you create a database that, when modified, can hack into the computer it opens, because it's not a real threat to you. But as I said, it's a bad plan, and you should avoid it when possible, and you can avoid it. Just as opening up your database to SQL injection is a bad practice. Only this is a lot more serious, as it can not only destroy your database, but also infect computers with whatever malware.

Comment: And you can mock me for actually wanting to help you build a proper, up-to-standards database application, or you can ask me for help, but you can't do both.

Comment: I don't know where you read that I'm mocking you. I think I clearly said that "while this probably doesn't apply (and listed why I think it doesn't apply) I'm curious on what the proper way of doing it Is. My 2nd message said that I'm also curious on the way it can be hacked. I reread my messages a few times and still don't see what can be taken for a mock

Comment: Well, saying things like _lol_ and _I don't think I care about hacks_ at least don't make me think you take me seriously. With so little information, it's hard to know exactly what I would do. Usually, you store data in the database, and code in the modules. I don't get exactly why you need specific code per entry. If you only have either `year(date)` or `date-365`, you could do a simple `Replace( MyColumnWithCode, "year(date)", year(date))`. But depending on what you're doing exactly, I would use something more sophisticated.

Comment: Lol to me is a smile, same as smiley face. Saying "I don't think I care" was my way of saying "here's my logic, let me know if I'm wrong". Def wasn't mocking and never would, even if someone said something I might think unlikely. I'm always interested to learn new things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157206/discussion-between-lalachka-and-erik-von-asmuth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Me.ProjectName="ddddd " & Eval(MyColumnWithCode)
```

but not with your present code. It has to read:

```
Year(Date())
Date()-365
```

Comment: I had this version originally lol, just without the Eval.  Then thought that I'm in VBA and it's Date not Date() lol. Thank you!! Now I'm curious why it's a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Simply write

```
dddd = sheets("Sheet1").range("a1").value
me.ProjectName= str(ddddd) & MyColumnWithCode    'Str is used in case its a number
```

Comment: This is for ms access but it's good to have the excel version for reference. Once I test it I will upvote it. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very sure about ms-access so I don't know why it doesn't work. But it should work in VBA.

Comment: i tried in excel, i understand this this is excel. my A1 value was year(date())