# storing variables in a field and using them to populate values

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is similar to this post [storing code in a column and using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861816/storing-code-in-a-column-and-using-it) but has another twist to it

So, I have a column that has stuff like

```
"Ddddd " & color & " blah blah " & width & "kdndjnsnd"
```

So, id like to run a query that will populate color and width from the values of those columns in a table. So each row will get populated with a value from those columns on that record.

For example

```
Color    Width    Code
Black    5        "Ddddd '" & color & "' blah blah " & width & " kdndjnsnd"
```

Will produce the following for that record

```
Ddddd black blah blah 5 kdndjnsnd"
```

I know that doing this isn't recommended. I'm open to suggestions on how to accomplish this. I have a bunch of fields that need to be populated with dynamic values. Those values are burried inside blocks of text.

ETA here's a link to an excel file with an example of what i'm trying to do
[excel file with an example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NxXXxFK_V1Zl3fh_Oe957d-ub-2Z2KsO)

Comment: What is your actual goal you want to achieve?

Comment: I updated my original. Look at the ETA

Comment: hey, did you see my answer? i added it into the original, since i can't format stuff in the comments.

Comment: I did, but it didn't help. :( Suggested reading: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). -- And your usage of "fields" is confusing.

Comment: "field" is what i thought columns are called in MS Access. maybe that word is used specifically for forms, i don't know, but it's definitely a valid word to use when referring to MS Access data. and i uploaded an excel example. i don't know how to explain this in words

Comment: is it better with the excel file?

Comment: Excel file did not help my understanding. You need to parse string into discrete data elements?

Comment: no, i don't need to parse it, i need to replace the variables (in my fields they look like this (" & Color & ") with data (Black, Gray, Brown, etc) from that row.. COLOR variable should be replaced with the color from column D, WIDTH variable should be replaced with the width from column E and so on. i'm trying to build dynamic strings based on the values on that row.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very convoluted way to do a simple thing.

General rule: Data belongs in **tables**. Calculated fields / expressions belong in **queries**.

All your table should contain is the actual data columns:

```
ProductType  Length  Hardware   Color   Width
```

Everything else belongs into a query:

```sql
SELECT
  "dddddd " & [Length] & " ft dddddd dog leash - dddddddd" AS ProductTitle,
  "https://blah.com/ddddddd-" & [Color] & "-" & [Width] & "-" & [Hardware] & "-dog-leash-1.png" AS MainImg,
  "https://blah.com/ddddddd-" & [Color] & "-" & [Width] & "-" & [Hardware] & "-ddddddd-1.png" AS Img1,
  -- etc.
FROM Product_Data
```

Comment: My table does have those values. The problem is that ddddd isn't always the same. It changes by the record type. So to do it this way I'd have to create a query for each record type. Another problem, this stuff will be edited pretty often. This is the purpose behind creating this automation, so that I can easily make the changes in 1 table and then rerun and recreate everything. I ended up writing an excel procedure that replaces the variables with cells.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized that I didn't explain this and didn't give enough examples to show that data changes by record type. I'm not by a computer now so I can't fix it. So you're right suggesting this based on the information I gave. I just didn't give enough information